# Repeat on iOS music app

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhone 5. I have the latest software update of iOS 10.0.2. How can I repeat a Playlist and song? 
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While a song is playing, pull up to reveal both the list of next titles and two buttons to enable/disable shuffle and to set the playlist or title to repeat.

[image]